# Is it possible to select all records where a field is null using LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a table that caches calculated values for certain dates. I want to use LINQ to select all rows where the calculated value fields are null.

But when I use isNothing I get an error that LINQ can't translate this into T-SQL. Is there a way to select null values with link, like this...?

```
Dim var = From rec As Record In myDataContext.Records Where IsNothing(rec.calculatedValue) Select rec
```

Other posts on stackoverflow mostly discuss how to avoid or check for null values with LINQ.

**Note**: I can't just set cacluatedValue's default to -1 to flag records whose calculated value has not been set (and then select those records) because I run queries that sum/average the calculated values. Selecting nulls seems cleaner and less bug-prone.

Comment: Can you show us the type of `calculatedValue`?

Comment: The datatype of the calculatedValue field in the database is Integer

Comment: Works for me. If the column is nullable on the server, `Is Nothing` gets translated into `IS NULL`.

Comment: Is the column nullable and what is the type of calculatedValue in the data context?

Comment: Stupid goof on my part. I was using IsNothing(calculated value) in my code but wrote it on stack overflow as calculatedValue isNothing. Apparently, only the second version of the syntax translates. I am changing the code in my question to use the wrong syntax, if you want to put it as an answer i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim var = (From rec As Record In myDataContext.Records _ 
    Where rec.calculatedValue is nothing _ 
    Select rec)
```